# Is the function an elementary solution?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Is the function : $u : C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb R^2) \rightarrow \mathbb C : f \rightarrow \int_\mathbb R f(t,t) dt$

an elementary ( a fundamental) solution of $\frac{d}{dx_1} + \frac{d}{dx_2}$ ?

I just began the course on distribution theory and I do not know how to start, any comment is welcome.

My attempt so far :

if $u$ is a fundamental solution of $\frac{d}{dx_1} + \frac{d}{dx_2}=:L$ , then $Lu = \delta $ , which means that for any $f \in C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb R^2)$, we have that $<Lu, f>=< \delta, f>= f (0,0)$

But $<Lu, f> = <u, -(\frac{d}{dx_1} + \frac{d}{dx_2}) f> = -(\int_\mathbb R \frac{d}{dx_1}f(t,t) dt + \int_\mathbb R \frac{d}{dx_2}f(t,t) dt)$

Now I have to show that this last term is equal to $f(0,0)$, but I cant find how...

Is my reasoning correct ?

Comment: Is the domain $\mathbb{R}^2$ so that it should be $u : C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2) \to \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Yes it is. I edit now

Comment: I think
$$-\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{df}{d x_{1}} (t, t) d t+\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{df}{d x_{2}} (t, t) d t\right) = - \int_{\mathbb R}  \frac{d}{d t}(f (t, t))dt = f(-\infty,-\infty)-f(+\infty,+\infty) = 0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first denote $L=\partial_1+\partial_2$. We have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
-\langle Lu, f\rangle & = \langle u, Lf\rangle = \int_\mathbb{R} (Lf)(t,t) {\,\rm d}t \,.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Besides, if $\phi(t)=(t,t)$, we have $\phi'(t)=(1,1)$ and
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(f(t,t))' & = (f\circ\phi(t))' \\
& = (\nabla f)(\phi(t))\cdot\phi'(t) \\
& =(\partial_1 f)(t,t)+(\partial_2 f)(t,t) \\
& = ((\partial_1 f)+(\partial_2 f))(t,t) \\
& = (Lf)(t,t)\,.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Hence
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
-\langle Lu, f\rangle & = \int_\mathbb{R} (Lf)(t,t) {\,\rm d}t \\
& = \int_\mathbb{R} (f(t,t))' {\,\rm d}t \\
& = f(t,t)\big|_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \\
& = 0\,,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
since ${\rm supp}\,f$ is compact.
The conclusion is that $Lu=0$.

Are you sure such $u$ is a fundamental solution for $L$?

Comment: It is asked **if**  this $u$ is a fundamental solution for $L$, not to show it. As you showed it, it is not the case. Thank you